# NSFetchRequest fails when using date as predicate

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I am trying to fetch all records from a core data entity that was created "today", I have a field in the Entity called createdDate that stores the date as string using local timeZone of the device in the following format

```
2017-06-26T11:06:43+08:00
```

I create the following date string for comparison:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterDayOnly = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatterDayOnly setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    [dateFormatterDayOnly setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

    NSString *todaysDate = [dateFormatterDayOnly stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Debugs tell me the Predicate looks ok as follows

```
2017-06-26 11:33:22.277 NWMobileTill[1842:482539] -[EodView tillTotalCashIn] todaysDate:2017-06-26
```

and then I create the predicate as follows

```
NSPredicate *predicateTodaysDate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"createdDate like[cd] %@", todaysDate];

    fetchPts.predicate = predicateTodaysDate;

    NSArray *todaysTendersArray = [[context executeFetchRequest:fetchPts error:&errorPts] mutableCopy];
```

But this returns 0 hits

I would have expected this to match all that were created today.

What do I need to change to make this return all records created today?

Comment: Yes as clearly stated in the question it is stored as strings

Comment: Why do you do that? And how did "Debug tells" you that string.

Comment: Is your question related to my question ?

Comment: Of course, highly.

Comment: How is it relevant ? And if so explain why

Comment: If you print a date object in the debugger (`po date`) it will print something like "2017-06-26T11:06:43+08:00" and it can be very to tell if it a string or a date. Are you sure it is a string?

Comment: You try to match with a period on time line. You try to do this with one of many possible representations and this include timezones. This can fail easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of `like[cd]` use `BEGINSWITH`

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"createdDate BEGINSWITH %@", todaysDate];
```

or regular expression evaluation:

```
NSString* regex = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"^%@.*$", todaysDate];
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"createdDate MATCHES %@", regex];
```

Answer (score 0):

Storing a date object as a string is **WRONG**.  It is not a little wrong.  It is not 'reasonable people will disagree wrong. It is complete wrong.

As a string you can't compare which is greater. You can't select a range. You can't sort by date.  And on top of that the one thing that you would think a string would do better - displaying the date as a string - is also harder!  Because of localization you have to parse the string into a date and then back into a correct localized string.

If you haven't release your app yet then simply change the type in the core-data model, delete the app, and reinstall.  Make sure that everyone else also deletes the app or it will crash for them.

If you have already release you app then create a new model version with ANOTHER property with the createdDate as a date.  When the app starts (but not in app delegate - because it may take more than 5 seconds and if it does then the OS will force quit the app) go though the database and parse all of the createdDate Strings and put them into the createdDate date field.

To do a search when the value is a `date` get the start and end of the date and search for values that are between the two.

```
NSDate* startOfDay = [self.calendar startOfDayForDate:[NSDate date]];
NSDate* endOfDay = [self.calendar dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay value:1 toDate:startOfDay options:0];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"createdDate > %@", startOfDay],[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"createdDate < %@", endOfDay]]];
```

Comment: My friend we already have different date fields in the model, so can we please stay relevant to the question, the question is not if it's right or wrong to store dates as strings,

Comment: My friend we already have different date fields in the model, so can we please stay relevant to the question, the question is not if it's right or wrong to store dates as strings,

Comment: The do the search based on the date field.

Comment: Again we are but that's not relevant to this question

Comment: So just to be clear: you have two fields. One called `createdDate` which is a string and another different field that also represents the createdDate, but is a date.  And both are set correctly.  When you search based on the date it works fine, but when you search based on the string it doesn't work.  And  the search MUST be done based on the string for reasons that you can't explain.  Is that correct?